# no main manifest in maven jar

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I've build [this project](https://github.com/andrevanzuydam/flyway) with `mvn clean install`. Now I have a `.jar` file but I'm not able to use it with:

```
λ java -jar flyway-commandline-xxx.jar
no main manifest attribute, in flyway-commandline-xxx.jar
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An executable jar needs a "manifest file" - which is located at `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the jar.

You can use the Maven Assembly plugin to produce this manifest file in line with this:

```
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>dk.tbsalling.ais.cli.AisCli</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

The `MainClass` (referenced in the manifest file) is the class containing the `main(...)`-method called when you execute the jar.

You can have a look at https://github.com/tbsalling/aiscli/blob/master/pom.xml for a full, working example.

Comment: Thanks this works! Do you know how I can achieve the same for a .tar.gz? Error: "Could not find or load main class org.xx.xx.Main"

Comment: You're welcome. I am not sure what you mean about the .tar.gz?

Comment: After the clean install I've a jar (which works now) and a .tar.gz. But when I'm using this tar.gz I'm facing  Error: Could not find or load main class "name-of-my-main-class"

Comment: But why would you "java -jar app.tar.gz" instead of "java -jar app.jar" ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Same old no manifest error. Is there a different way now?

Answer (score 0):

Use below 2 maven plugins in pom.xml:

1. maven-assembly-plugin with a goal to package all dependencies.
2. maven-jar-plugin along with this to add manifest and make jar with the dependencies included by assembly plugin.

Since, in assembly plugin below, appendAssemblyId is false, so final jar name will be with appname.jar only.
You can test assembly using command: "mvn clean compile assembly:single". (or using Jenkins JPaC file then add the command "clean compile assembly:single" under mavenGoals).

See below:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>appname</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.myorg.appname.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.myorg.appname.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```